# There should be a prize for the top user in area 51

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, fun

Whoever this handsome guy is, I'm sure he'd welcome anything from stickers, to a nice t-shirt with aliens.

**Edit**: I was contacted 1.5 hours after posting this by the kind Emily from Stack Overflow Inc.

I didn't want to say anything before because I was unsure the awesome prizes I deserved would arrive, as my country has some weird customs.

Nevertheless, I have proof now that the team takes every feature-request seriously:

[image: He was very handsome after all!]

[image: Personal message]

[image: Close up]

Comment: *be a price*?  Are you implying we sell <del>you</del><ins>the top user</ins>?

Comment: @Rebecca, I have no idea what you're talking about (thanks to the 5 minutes edit "graze" period)

Comment: @Juan Manuel, due to a case of extreme coïncidence, this guy uses the same name as you.

Comment: looking *sharp*

Comment: Golly. I have one of those, but mine didn't come with a smiley face.

Comment: Excellent!  Yay, Argentinian postal system! [Could one also say "Argentine," or does that imply silver?]

Comment: Boy did I miss out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice idea.

Thanks to a gift from my universal connections, the top user of Area 51 now owns a small piece of land on [Gliese 581c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_581_c). Just be sure to build a settlement within the next 25 years, else the powers that be will reclaim this space as unoccupied.

If the top user is a lady, maybe [the planet sized diamond](http://wn.com/Giant_Planet_Sized_Diamond_Found_Floating_in_Space) was a better prize. But this one is already promised to somebody else.

Comment: Gliese is a stone's throw away from Terminus E17. It shouldn't be a problem for him to build there

Comment: OMG, that is an excellent prize!

Comment: I have got to find a way to get [adverse possession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_possession) of extraterrestrial objects....

Answer (score 1):

I think we already know who they are:

[image]